# Integral Cauchy formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How do I put:

$\int_\gamma (z + \frac{1}{z})^{2n}  \frac{dz} {z} $

In the form:
 $\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{2n}} $

Initially I have gone for $f(z)=\frac {1}{z} $ but I cannot get the rest in that form any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just take the LCM and separate the numerator and denominator $$f\left(z\right)=\left(z^{2 }+1 \right)^{2 n}\ $$
$$ \left(z \right)^{2 n+1 }=\left(z-0\right)^{2 n+1 }\ $$

Comment: Thanks , Is f(z) holomorphic?

Comment: @jamesjameison, Yes! f(z) is holomorphic. Since $z^2 +1$ is holomorphic, f(z) is also holomorphic.